# Read specific lines of a text file [C#]

Tags: c#

I'am trying to read content of a text file.

And store it in a string.

Example :

Text file contains :

```
Globalization = "0x000000"
HookWindow = "0x000000"
Blabla = "0x000000"
Etc = "0x000000"
```

I'd like to store them in a string and be able to retrieve that content in a label for example.

So I can say :

```
String Globalization = GlobalizationInTheTextFile;
```

And be able to use `label.1.text = Globalization;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath)
                    .Select(i => i.Split(new[] { " = \"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    .ToDictionary(i => i[0], j => j[1].TrimEnd('\"'));

string globalization = dictionary["Globalization"];
```

Assuming your file is of the structure `key = "value"` and each Key-Value-Pair is on a new line, this allows you to get any `value` via `dictionary["key"]`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `File.ReadAllLines` static method to store all lines in `string[]` array and then use LINQ methods to get one specific line starting with `Globalization`.

```
string Globalization = File.ReadAllLines("path")
  .Where(s => s.StartsWith("Globalization"))
  .First().Split('=')[1].Trim().Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: Thank you, that works just fine as test I used :

`string Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Offset.ini").Where(s => s.StartsWith("Globalization")).First();
            Console.WriteLine(Lines);
            Console.ReadKey();`


Which returns to : "Globalization = "0x123456789"
Is it possible to get the "0x123456789" part only ?

Comment: @Mila I added method to get the desired part only. If my answer helped you you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: It did thank you, apparently I'am not allowed to upvote
"Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

```
string globalizationPrefix = "Globalization = ";
string globalizationLine = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith(globalizationPrefix ))
    .FirstOrDefault();

if(globalizationLine != null)
{
    int index = globalizationPrefix.Length;
    string globalizationValue = globalizationLine.Substring(index);
    label1.Text = globalizationValue;
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know you shouldn't be using `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` in the same query as you do. The correct way would be `File.ReadAllLines(filePath).FirstOrDefault(i => i.StartsWith(globalizationPrefix))`